# How to search for a directory and then change directory to it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to search for a directory on my windows computer and then cd to it.
For example:

```
find directory
cd output of previous command
```

I'm planning to put this in a .bat file then run it by typing in the file name

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than one "directory" name is found?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, you state you're wanting to search for a directory on your Windows computer, yet you're wanting to run it by typing on a file name! Also, you'll need to explain why you're having to search for this on your computer, surely you can locate it before you create the script! If you really wanted to locate a directory using internal commands, I'd invite you to open a Command Prompt window and enter `dir /?` to learn how the command options work for directories. Once you've got that command as you need it, do the same with `for /?` and integrate them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %d in (`dir /s /b <directory>`) DO cd "%d %e"
```

It uses `for /f` to evaluate each line of the output.

It sepcifies `usebackq` so that you can pass a command as an argument inside the braces.

It defines `tokens=1*` so that there is another variable after `%d` which captures the rest of the line.

It then `CD`s into each directory of the output, so the final directory will be the **last** one of the output.

In this example I use `dir /s /b` to get a clean output of what I'm looking for. I specified a directory name, so I could directly CD to it. If you want to use a file name instead, simply step up one level using an additional `..`:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %d in (`dir /s /b <filename>`) DO cd "%d %e\.."
```